# How to run function before fullscreenchange in Javascript

Tags: javascript, fullscreenchange

I have a function in Javascript that need to be called BEFORE event fullscreenchange occurs.

As stated on MDN, The fullscreenchange event is fired immediately AFTER the browser switches into or out of fullscreen mode.

Is there's any thing like this:

```
document.addEventListener('beforefullscreenchange', handlerFunction);
```

Thank you

Comment: You'll likely need to add a function to the button or interactive element which fires the fullscreen event

Comment: I believe if you check the state of the document using the document.fullscreen property you can run your function before running the fullscreen request function

Comment: Certainly your call to `Element.requestFullscreen()` is itself done in an user-gesture handler, like in a click event. Can't you just listen to that same triggerer?

Comment: thank you so much for all of your advices